# How to drop partitioned index in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, partitioning

I am unable to drop partitioned index due to partition scheme and partition function existence.

Table has a Primary Key, a Clustered Index and non clustered indexes.

I am running the following query:

```
drop partition scheme scheme_name
```

I am getting this error:

> Msg 7717, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The partition scheme "scheme_name" is currently being used to partition one or more tables.

I tried recreating indexes by dropping them but I still get the same error.

Comment: Please include the schema of the table in question.

Answer (score 0):

After performing one of many partition Switch operations in a Pruning process I had problems with 1 table where I could not remove the Partition Scheme at the end of the process.

Turns out, when re-building the Clustered Index back onto a single FileGroup you MUST explicitly refer to a filegroup in the statement and not assume it will go to the Default filegroup. If FileGroup is Empty the existing Partition Scheme is assumed.

-- Re-Create the Clustered Index with no Partition

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex_PK 
ON MyTable([MyID]) 
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON )  
ON MustReferToMyFileGroupHere;
```

Hope this helps someone.  Applies to at least SQL 2012